VBA Word Macro: How to Replace Page Number Fields in Headers and Footers with Plain Text?
I’m working on a VBA macro for Microsoft Word and need to replace page number fields in headers and footers with plain text. Specifically, I want to:

Replace all page number fields in headers and footers with plain
text.
Remove the fields without leaving any remaining field codes.

I tried using fld.Result.InsertBefore and fld.Result.InsertAfter to insert the text next to the fields, but these methods don’t work as expected.
Sub EliminarCodigosCampo()
    Dim sec As Section
    Dim hdr As HeaderFooter
    Dim ftr As HeaderFooter
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim fieldText As String

    ' Select the entire content of the document
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Fields.Unlink

    ' Convert automatic numbering to text
    ActiveDocument.ConvertNumbersToText

    ' First pass: Copy the page number field value and insert it as plain text
    For Each sec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        ' Loop through all headers
        For Each hdr In sec.Headers
            For Each fld In hdr.Range.Fields
                fieldText = fld.Result.Text
                fld.Result.InsertBefore fieldText
            Next fld
        Next hdr
        ' Loop through all footers
        For Each ftr In sec.Footers
            For Each fld In ftr.Range.Fields
                fieldText = fld.Result.Text
                fld.Result.InsertBefore fieldText
            Next fld
        Next ftr
    Next sec

    ' Second pass: Remove page number fields and their content
    For Each sec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        ' Loop through all headers
        For Each hdr In sec.Headers
            Do While hdr.Range.Fields.Count > 0
                hdr.Range.Fields(1).Unlink
                hdr.Range.Fields(1).Result.Delete
            Loop
        Next hdr
        ' Loop through all footers
        For Each ftr In sec.Footers
            Do While ftr.Range.Fields.Count > 0
                ftr.Range.Fields(1).Unlink
                ftr.Range.Fields(1).Result.Delete
            Loop
        Next ftr
    Next sec
End Sub

Problem:
The methods fld.Result.InsertBefore and fld.Result.InsertAfter don’t seem to work as intended. How can I correctly replace page number fields in headers and footers with plain text using VBA?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

If you change the fields to plain text each page in the section will have the same number. You could overcome this by ensuring that each section contains only 1 page, but that would be very unwise.

@TimothyRylatt You are right, I overlooked that aspect. What I intend to do is impossible to implement.
